# Call code from module and execute it since a chosing option in menu

Tags: crystal-lang

I don't understand why when I execute my code and I chose the first option he left without doing anything.
You will find below the code of my crystal script.

```
require "colorize"
class Application

  def initialize
    mainMenu
  end

  def mainMenu
    puts "you are going to install the software?"
    puts " 1: To install the soft you have to be root".colorize.fore(:red).bold
    puts " 2: Modify module"

    case gets
    when "1"
      puts "installation of the software.."
      install_soft

    when "2"
      puts "you chose option2"
    end
  end

  Application.new
end
```

This is the code of my install module with the methode install_soft. 
He print correctly my `puts " you are .."` but it does nothing else :(

```
module InstallSoft
  def install_soft
    puts "you are in def install_soft "
    output = IO::Memory.new
    Process.run("bash", args: {"eole/lib/bash_scripts/installation.sh"}, output: output)
    output.close
    output.to_s
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to see the stack in live with output:true

```
 Process.run("lib/bash_scripts/installation.sh", shell: true, output: true, error: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, what should it do? Your collecting the stdout of the process in a memory IO and convert it to string.

If you want to print the stdout of the process to the stdout of your app, you'll either have to forward it (use `STDOUT` instead of memory IO) or print the content of the memory IO to stdout (`puts install_soft`).

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution i've to use

```
 Process.run("lib/bash_scripts/installation.sh", shell: true, output: output)
          output.close
          output.to_s
```

but for the moment i cant get the output of my script :(

Comment: `puts output` should print out your output. Also, ensure installation script produce any output to capture.